# How to Normalize (database) relationship between User, Quotes, and Tags?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization

I am working on an app that displays quotes, much like BrilliantQuotes in Android. I am working on table design and I cannot come up with a solution on how tables User, Quotes, and Tags should be related/designed/normalized. 
The relation would be something like:

1. A User can have 0 or many Tags.
2. A Tag could have 0 or many Quotes and a Quote could have 0 or many Tags.

First part is fairly simple, I will have a foreign key column on Tags table to identify the User. For the second part, how do I represent that relation? I cannot just added a Quotes FK to the Tags table or vice-versa, because then it won't be normalized, isn't it? Also, since I will allow Users to create their own tags, I could have many rows with a same TagName for instance 'Funny', which I think would be necessary since  the tags would be user specific OR is there a better approach to that?

Comment: Think like math:  4*3 = 12 and so is 3*4 = 12....so #2 is really one thing:  A Quote can have zero or more tags.  Period.  You will be able to query for either tags per quote or quotes per tag.

Comment: @Stan - But that would make things not so great in terms of scalability, isn't it? Let's take this famous quote for instance "Never ever ever give up." with tags like "Inspirational" "Motivational" "Cool" "Awesome", and now if I have a FK for Tags on Quotes table, I will be repeating the same quote with only difference between the rows being the Tags. Imagine this for several Users, since tag is going to be tied to a User.  It would be a similar thing if I go about having FK for Quotes in Tags table. Is this  really how those apps could be approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an intersection table

With very sparse definitions, something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users ( id int identity, username varchar(99))
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tags  ( TagID INT Identity, taglabel varchar(99), ownerid INT)
CREATE TABLE dbo.Quotes ( QuoteID INT Identity, quoteText varchar(max))
```

Then

```
 CREATE TABLE QuoteTagMap (QTID INT identity, QuoteID INT, TagID int)
```

You would add rows to QuoteTagMap to store the relationships between tags and quotes.  If you wanted to allow different users to have different tags for the same quote...then the map would also have an OwnerID

Comment: Two notes to your solution: a) don't forget to add the foreign key constraints; b) `QTID` in `QuoteTagMap` does not add any information and should be removed, the primary key of the table should be the combination of the other attributes.

Comment: Yes, I left out FKs.   But I disagree abuot `QTID` -- this PK makes UI logic to delete tags easier.  I would define  QuoteID, TagID as a   clustering `AK` index and use QTID for updates.

Comment: In my opinion the gain of reducing the record size, so to have more records per page, and reduce the number of pages, so to speed up the retrieval of records, is greater than having a field for easing the UI logic, but I understand that you can have a different experience from my own.

Comment: This is half the solution. OP describes a m-n relationship between users and tags and an independent m-n relationship between quotes and tags. This calls for an intersection between Users and Tags and also between Quotes and Tags.

Comment: I didn't feel there were enough specifics to handle the user/tag mapping, and was hoping to get the **concept** of an intersection table across.  User/Tag mappings need to deal with fundamental questions:  do we have totally independent tags (with unique IDs) that happen to have the label "Funny", or is there a global universe of tags...so that multiple users store their relationship with the global funny tag?  And when *I* want a new Hilarious tag, is that added to the global set, or just my personal set? Like I said, questions...